Broke dot repeat. Where to begin troubleshooting?
A few weeks back my dot repeat functionality completed ceased working. I believe I broke some part of my configuration around the time I made changes to migrate the plugin manager from Packer to Lazy. Unfortunately I cannot be sure it didn't happen prior and I don't have regular commits on the dotfile repo.
To be clear, the dot key now simply does nothing.
I'm on Neovim 0.10.1 MacOS with an all Lua config and checkhealth reveals no errors.
So my question is, short of reducing my configuration down to zero and gradually restoring, what is the best way to begin troubleshooting this problem? Specifically, I'm hoping to understand if there are any typical known causes of this kind of problem that I can investigate and address directly rather than having to go through a tedious process of elimination.
If there any specific issues I need to be looking for (i.e. config errors that prevent dot repeat config from loading or perhaps config that overwrites the dot repeat function) then I would be tremendously grateful for any insight.

Seeing if :map . shows anything would be a place to start.

Welcome to Vim! I would start by running the :nmap . command (to make sure the . command has not been overload). I would run the :reg . command (to see if the . register is not overwritten).

Go to resources: How to debug my vimrc
How to debug a mapping

Did you solved your problem? Did some of the answer helped you? If you have a solution we will be glad to have an answer from you :-) Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Here are some way to make the . operator not working:

Override the . operator
Have trigger that override the . register

To investigate the first problem run the following Vim command:
:nmap .

The return value should be:
No mapping found

To investigate the second run the following Vim command:
:reg .

The return value should be the content of your last insertion.
